# request for assistance (postgresql) min/max functions

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, group-by

I am new at postgres and comes up with following issue. I need to answer the question if there are cities where economy price is cheaper than business. Currently my request is as following:

```
with cte_money as (
    select  
        ad.city ->> 'ru' as city,
        fare_conditions, 
        amount
    from ticket_flights tf   
    join flights as f using(flight_id)
    join airports_data as ad on f.arrival_airport = ad.airport_code 
    order by city, fare_conditions asc
    )
    select  
        city,
        (select max(amount) where fare_conditions = 'Economy') as Max_Economy,
        (select min(amount) where fare_conditions = 'Business') as Min_Business
    from cte_money
    group by city, fare_conditions
    order by city asc
```

It gives the following result (yellow):
[image]

How to merge max in min values for the same city in a single row and compare values with each other? In summary I need to display only cities where economy class is cheaper than business. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question and schema, there is no need for CTEs or nested queries. You can just use aggregation and a `having` clause for filtering:

```
select ad.city ->> 'ru' as city,
from ticket_flights tf   
join flights as f using(flight_id)
join airports_data as ad on f.arrival_airport = ad.airport_code 
group by ad.city ->> 'ru'
having 
    max(amount) filter (where fare_conditions = 'Economy') 
    < min(amount) filter(where fare_conditions = 'Business') 
order by city
```

You can repeat the conditional `min()` and `max()` in the `select` clause if you want to display them in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

For this group by query you need no subselects when you put the conditions into the aggregate. Then, you can easily filter for a cheaper economy class with a having clause:

```
with cte_money as (
    select  
        ad.city ->> 'ru' as city,
        fare_conditions, 
        amount
    from ticket_flights tf   
    join flights as f using(flight_id)
    join airports_data as ad on f.arrival_airport = ad.airport_code 
    order by city, fare_conditions asc
    )
    select  
        city,
        max(CASE WHEN fare_conditions = 'Economy' THEN amount ELSE NULL END) as Max_Economy,
        min(CASE WHEN fare_conditions = 'Business' THEN amount ELSE NULL END) as Min_Business 
    from cte_money
    group by city, fare_conditions
    HAVING max(CASE WHEN fare_conditions = 'Economy' THEN amount ELSE NULL END) <= min(CASE WHEN fare_conditions = 'Business' THEN amount ELSE NULL END)
    order by city asc
```